# How to remove duplicate/unwanted auth routes from route list in laravel?

Tags: laravel

For example:

```
URI
GET  login LoginController@showLoginForm
POST login LoginController@login
```

Comment: Could you explain why you want it? What's your goal? Maybe the URL is the same, but the method differs on those two routes.

Comment: When I call login route then it automatically redirect to admin/login that's why

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where do you call a login route? What's your purpose? Did you write your own login form and logic?

Comment: Yes In my project, there are two separate login for admin and front-end but front side two login route is run so i want only one of them not both.For example: when write "mydomain/login" in browser then it automicaly redirect to "mydomain/admin/login" that i dosen't want

Comment: I think it has more to do with how the routes are setup. It sounds like there is a middleware active that checks whether a user is logged in or not at the first login url already and redirects to the second.

Comment: POST admin AdminLoginController@login web,guest
GET|HEAD admin AdminLoginController@showLoginForm web,guest      
POST admin/login LoginController@login web,guest      
GET|HEAD admin/login login LoginController@showLoginForm web,guest
GET|HEAD login login LoginController@showLoginForm web,guest      
POST login LoginController@login web,guest

Answer (score 1):

They are not duplicate routes. The URL is same but the method is not same. You need both the routes to login.

Auth::routes() is the shorthand for the following routes.

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

You can use either the shorthand or the routes above. And now if you want to change anything in the routes don't use the shorthand. Rather use the above routes and make necessary changes according to your needs.
By the way in the shorthand method, I believe you can do something like this if you don't want to use the register routes.

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have mentioned above, it doesn't have duplicate route.

GET login LoginController@showLoginForm :- This uses get method which will be used to show the login form where the user will provide its input like username and password.

where as in another route that is

POST login LoginController@login:- Here the user is using the POST method which will send those information ( username and password ) to the server for validating the user.

Comment: actually same contrroller actions called by another route like "admin/login" in frontside while admin part is different so two route points to same method at front-side that i dosen't want.

Comment: In that case you can either create separate controller for admin and others.